# Juice UI Selectable doesn't fire selected event

Tags: jquery-ui, juice-ui

Hi i'm using JuiceUI in my project but I'm having a problem with the Juice selectable control. It does not seem to fire the selected event when a selection is made in the list. I google'd and read somewhere that not all of the events trigger a postback which kicks of the event. But not even that seems to work. I have a button on the page which triggers a postback but it still does not trigger the selected event.

```
            <style>
                #feedback {font-size: 1.4em;}
                #lstActionList .ui-selecting {background: #FECA40;}
                #lstActionList .ui-selected {background: #F39814; color: white;}
                #lstActionList {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;}
                #lstActionList li { margin: 6px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1em; height: 18px;}
            </style>
            <ol id="lstActionList" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                <li class="ui-widget-content">Stock Requisition</li>
                <li class="ui-widget-content">Non-Stock Requisition</li>
                <li class="ui-widget-content">Service Requisition</li>
            </ol>
            <juice:Selectable ID="ActionListSelector" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="lstActionList" onselected="ActionListSelector_Selected" />
```

I have a breakpoint in my ActionListSelector_Selected method but it never reaches it.

I'm hoping that i'm missing something simple? Why doesn't the selected event trigger?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a server event named "onselected". There is however, an event named "Selected". Please browse the documentation here - http://juiceui.com/controls/selectable

Comment: Hi I have tried Selected but I get an Parser Error. Here is a screenshot [link](http://screencast.com/t/UhcPiA7Z) of the error. When I go to the properties of the control and double click on the selected event it also auto generates the onselected attribute on the control.